# jQuery Validation with regex

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I used jQuery Validation Plugin to validate email, username, password...and I have tried to add some regex but it wasn't work. Can someone help me? Many thanks.[here is the picture of regex I tried to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkeql.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].   In this case, you'd be expected to include the original (working) code and the code as you changed it, along with what you are trying to achieve.  Please include code as either a snippet or simply by indenting with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'pattern:' to match the regex expression. Below code shows regex matching for string. Hope it serves your purpose.

```
$("#your_form").validate({
rules: {
    yourelementName: {
        required:true,
        pattern: /^[a-zA-Z'.\s]{1,40}$/  //this line validates the element with the provided regex expression
    },
},
messages: {
    yourelementName: {
        required:'Please enter the data'
        pattern: 'The Textbox string format is invalid'
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are no script errors in ur page ? you can check it in the console. If there are any errors validation might fail .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#name').focusout(function () {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
    if (pattern.test($("#name").val())) {
        $("#name").css('border-color',
            'green') v1 = 1
    } else {
        $("#name").css('border-color', 'red') v1 = 0
    }
});
```

**Do like this, use event you like to validate text box.**

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code if it solve your problem

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Your input."
 );
```

do validate like below

```
 $("#field").rules("add", { regex: "^[a-zA-Z'.\\s]{1,40}$" })
```